# Why I got WM_CLOSE message after clicking the button?

Tags: windows, win32gui

I just want to click the button and change the text of the button, however, I would get the `WM_CLOSE` message, it confused me.

```
const wchar_t *g_szClassName = L"myWindowClass";
HWND hwnd;
HWND hButtonLine;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                hButtonLine = CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", L"change title", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 20, 50, 150, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_CHANGE_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
                break;
            }
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (HIWORD(wParam)) {
                case BN_CLICKED:
                    SetWindowText(hButtonLine, L"You clicked the button");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        case WM_CLOSE:
            if (MessageBox(hwnd, L"Really quit?", L"My application", MB_OKCANCEL) == IDOK)
            {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        L"Happy Today",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 450, 250,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Step through the `BN_CLICKED` message and you may notice an unexpected fallthrough due to a missing `break`.

Comment: The WM_COMMAND case is missing `break;`

Answer (score 0):

oh, thks @RaymondChen, I missed the `break` here.

[image]